# Difficulties with regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to get `12.1.0.2.170117` from `PSU 12.1.0.2.170117`. The pattern `([\d|\.]+)` seems to work fine: https://regex101.com/r/bDCF0w/1

However, it does not work as expected in Oracle's regexp_replace: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d64e/77. Do I miss something? Why does it also return `PSU`, when I only have `\d` and `\`. in my expression?

My text could as well be `PSU SOMTHING SOMTHING 12.1.0.2.170117 AND HERE SOME.` 
My final goal is to also get read of first 3 dots.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This link https://regex101.com/r/bDCF0w/1 from your question works for **PHP Regex engine** but not for Oralce's regex engine. I don't know any online tester which supports Oracle regex implementation, you cannot rely on regexp checkers in case of Oracle.

Comment: In my question I wanted to get `12.1.0.2.170117`, which you did in your answer. The final goal is to get `12102.170117`.

Comment: If you want to test a DB's regex - use a DB-Fiddle:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tPTuFomAKYYNaVaJ61LLuT/0 (this is a postrgre fiddle)

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks for your answer, but your link does not have Oracle database. Only PostreSQL and SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with 
a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('PSU 12.1.0.2.170117', '^.*?([0-9.]+).*$', '\1')
FROM dual;
```

The approach above is to isolate and capture any quantity of dots or numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Could you, please, explain what does `?` do in this case? And why changing `0-9` to `\d` breaks it?

Comment: The `.*?` at the beginning of the pattern means consume up until the _first_ dot or number.  This prevents the pattern from inadvertently consuming part of the IP address.  `\d` appears to not work inside a character class, at least not in Oracle.  But `[0-9]` and `\d` are equivalent.

Comment: This one doesn't return the correct result for input string = `PSU SOMTHING SOMTHING 12.1.0.2.170117 AND HERE SOME` ... Not because of you, but missing info.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for that, I fixed it by including anchors on both ends of the pattern.

Comment: That's much better :)

Answer (score 4):

How about these two options:

```
SQL> with test (col) as (select 'PSU 12.1.0.2.170117' from dual)
  2  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+.+') result1,
  3         substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) result2
  4  from test;

RESULT1         RESULT2
--------------- ---------------
12.1.0.2.170117 12.1.0.2.170117

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Well, you should have said so. Here's yet another option - remove parts of a string that aren't numbers nor dots:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'PSU 12.1.0.2.170117' from dual union all
  3     select 'PSU SOMTHING SOMTHING 12.1.0.2.170117 AND HERE SOME' from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_replace(col, '[^[:digit:].]')
  6  from test;

REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'[^[:DIGIT:].]')
---------------------------------------------------
12.1.0.2.170117
12.1.0.2.170117

SQL>
```

Comment: The problem is that the original string could have anything in it, it could as well be `PSU SOMTHING SOMTHING 12.1.0.2.170117 AND HERE SOME`. Also, I need to use regexp_replace, because my final goal is to also get read of first 3 dots. The problem is that it seems that regexp_replace doesn't work as I expect it to work.

Comment: @stee1rat The problem is that you didn't tell us your actual problem.  Hence, three people went off and answered the wrong question.

Comment: I kind of tell you the actual problem: regexp_replace return the wrong group `PSU 12.1.0.2.170117` instead of `12.1.0.2.170117`.

Comment: I've edited my message, based on new info you posted.